# Error al enviar un correo por gmail

Tags: python, django

Tengo un proyecto en un servidor gratuito de heroku, desde el cual estoy tratando de enviar un correo usando un correo gmail, pero me da un error de auntenticacion como si las credenciales estuvieran erroneas.

Datos:

-Las credenciales son correctas, pues en el servidor local el correo se envia perfectamente, el problema me sucede cuando lo subo al servidor.

- Ya tengo activa la opcion de permitir el acceso de apps menos seguras (Repito en el servidor local el correo se envia perfectamente)

Esta es mi configuracion en settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST="smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_USE_TLS=True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

Este es el error que me da

```
>>> smtpserver.login('xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 732, in login
    raise last_exception
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 721, in login
    (code, resp) = self.auth(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 644, in auth
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (534, b'5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbu\n5.7.14 w8ZUho3b2TmmyWM9fKff3D2xNLTXMc5TxGm5gNGciFOpGsMGX2xXAKFJb_4D9iQS9GwUN\n5.7.14 7mqKqphSkCQAwvBbi6bcAUA3Mx1Nt3VeL8eLdclT5s7Ik9CKx2sKWQ8ZYKtXZ1CK>\n5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again.\n5.7.14  Learn more at\n5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 e28sm239779qtg.24 - gsmtp')
```

Toda ayuda es bien recibida. Gracias de antemano!

Comment: No debes usar tu contraseña de gmail para enviar correos (ni siquiera con "permitir aceso de aplicaciones menos seguras"). Google detectará un intento de login desde una IP inusual, y lo aborta. Debes ir a la configuración de seguridad de tu cuenta de google y entrar en "contraseñas de aplicaciones" para crear una. Después usas esa contraseña en lugar de la tuya en la configuración de heroku. Si esto te funciona puedes desactivar lo de permitir aplicaciones menos seguras.

Comment: ¿Has probado a usar smtp-relay.gmail.com como EMAIL_HOST? Google lo recomienda aquí: https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=es#zippy=%2Cutilizar-el-servidor-smtp-de-gmail

Comment: También puedes hacer lo que te indica el mensaje de error, es decir, visitar la URL que aparece en dicho mensaje, y hacer login en ella desde tu navegador. Es la forma de que google "confíe" en que el intento de login desde esa IP "rara" era legítimo, y en teoría ya te permitiría usar smtp desde ella. Pero es posible queotro día  la IP de heroku cambie y tengas el mismo problema. Insisto en que es más fácil y más seguro crear una "contraseña de aplicación".

Comment: Ya resolvi el problema usando el consejo de @abulafia creando una "contraseña de aplicación". Me ahorraste horas de dolor de cabeza. Muchas gracias a ambos!